# Pester test if the module is existing. Should not throw specific ExceptionType

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

Is it only me or the Pester if extremely hard to grab?

In the `BeforeAll` scriptblock I would like to test if the `ActiveDirectory` module is existing on the local machine.

The test should not throw exception type `[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]`

**Question 1:**

What is the correct/best approach?

```
Get-Module Module| Remove-Module -Force
Import-Module Module
Import-Module Pester

InModuleScope Module{

    Describe 'Add-Patchgroup' {

        BeforeAll {
            It 'Should import module ActiveDirectory' {
                {Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop } | Should -Not -Throw -ExceptionType {[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error when I run this on machine where AD module is not available:**

```
Describing Add-Patchgroup
  [-] Should import module ActiveDirectory 99ms
    PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]" value of type "System.Management.Auto
mation.ScriptBlock" to type "System.Type".
    ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]" value of type "Syste
m.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to type "System.Type".
    ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ExceptionType'
. Cannot convert the "[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to typ
e "System.Type".
```

**Question 2:**

Also consider there is a module named `ComplexModule` which is very time consuming to Import. Therefore I would like to mock the `Import-Module -Name ComplexModule` cmdlet. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test for whether an exception has been thrown needs to specify the exception as a string:

```
It 'Should import module ActiveDirectory' {
    {Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop } | Should -Not -Throw -ExceptionType System.IO.FileNotFoundException
}
```

You could `Mock` your `Import-Module` as follows:

```
Mock Import-Module {} -ParameterFilter {$Name -eq 'ComplexModule'}
```

Beware that you may have issues using `Import-Module` successfully/legitimately in your Pester script after you've mocked it, but so long as you use it before the Mock I think you'll be OK.

Note also that this Mock does nothing (hence the empty `{}`) so it effectively ensures the module is not loaded. If your tests rely on the module being loaded, you'll need to either not `Mock` it or find a way to load the needed commands otherwise.

Comment: modified my code but still not passing:   [-] Should import module ActiveDirectory 82ms
    Expected no exception to be thrown, but an exception "The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because
no valid module file was found in any module directory." was thrown from line:11 char:18

Comment: Suggests where you are running the test the AD module is not available.

Comment: running the test where the AD module is not available. here is the prtscr: https://ibb.co/mDaVb8 (do not mind other tests)

Comment: So you've written a test that checks that `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` does not throw a file not found exception. It does throw a file not found exception because its not installed on your system, hence your test fails, hence you get red text.

Comment: ohhh! *blushing* *facepalm*